# strange behaviour when submitting form 2nd time

Tags: c#, html, forms, razor, kendo-ui

I am using kendo window and Ajax.BeginForm() within a partial view bound to a model.
The window is rendered directly into the stream.

```
    @{
        Html.Kendo().Window()
            .Name("name")    
                .Content(
                        @<text>                           
                            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("PostReview", "Review", new AjaxOptions
                            {
                                HttpMethod = "Post",
                                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                OnSuccess = "onSuccessreviewOrderDialogForm",
                            }, new
                            {
                                @id = "reviewOrderDialogForm"
                            }))
                            {

                                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.OrderReviewId)
        ...
         }
                         </text>
                    )
 .Draggable()
        .Visible(false)
        .Modal(true)
        .Render();
}
```

Here is the thing:
After posting the first model, the following posts will always store the previous value (first model) for `OrderReviewId`.
Now I know that the *HtmlHelpers* will always use the values of the post back from the server but in this case I do not see the problem.
After posting the window is beeing closed. After that the new model (with correct values) is beeing passed to the same partial view including the `kendo window` and rendered with the new! model. Debug mode shows correct values for all fields.
But by posting, the value for `OrderReviewId` remains the old one.
How is that even possible? And why aren't the other fields (not shown here) correct - they are also HtmlHelper fields.

Thanks

Comment: I also tryed using '<input type="hidden" name="OrderReviewId" value="@Model.OrderReviewId"/>' which behaves exactly the same. The postback doesn't seem to be the problem here

Comment: Check two thing first when you are coming to the page anything which you are sending in url(Querystring) is breaking and second thing is check catching

Comment: Querystrings are good. As I said - the new model is actually beeing passed to the partial view. How can I test for caching?

Comment: Besides: If caching would be the problem, how come that only this very field is affected?

Comment: Inspect element and check net there it will show if data are changed or not

Comment: I don't get your point I am sorry.

Comment: Are you posting OrderReviewID = 0 the first time, updating the value on the server and then returning the updated view/model?  If so, MVC will always return the same values as posted, i.e. even if you set OrderReviewID  = 1 in your model in your controller action, the view/model returned will still have OrderReviewID = 0.  This is apparently by design.  You need to ModelState.Clear() in order for server-side changes to your Model.  See https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/apr/20/aspnet-mvc-postbacks-and-htmlhelper-controls-ignoring-model-changes for a better explanation than I can give.

Comment: No - that was not my use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you have some artifacts left over from the previous instance of the window. Can you ensure that your dialog is entirely removed from the dom after you close it. Something like:

```
if ($("#frmTest")!= null){
   $("#frmTest").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
   $("#frmTest").empty(); 
}
```

Comment: @ Ross Bush: that was exactly what caused the problem. After I destroyed the window, the problem was solved. Very strange though...